# bcrypt on ubuntu is not compiling or installing

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, npm, bcrypt

I am trying to install bcrypt using `npm i bcrypt` command on AWS Ubuntu EC2 instance however, it returns below error. It was working fine before this but it does not seem to be working now somehow.

```
  > bcrypt@1.0.3 install /home/ubuntu/dne/ne-backend/node_modules/bcrypt
  > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

  node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.3-node-v59-linux-x64.tar.gz
  node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.3 and node@9.8.0 (node-v59 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
  gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
  gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
  gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
  make: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/dne/ne-backend/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
  In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:192:0,
                   from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
  ../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: In function 'Nan::Maybe<bool> Nan::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)':
  ../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:112:73: warning: 'v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)' is deprecated: Use CreateDataProperty / DefineOwnProperty [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     return obj->ForceSet(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
                                                                           ^
  In file included from /home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/9.8.0/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                   from /home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/9.8.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                   from ../../nan/nan.h:49,
                   from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
  /home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/9.8.0/include/node/v8.h:3165:29: note: declared here
                   Maybe<bool> ForceSet(Local<Context> context, Local<Value> key,
                               ^
  /home/ubuntu/.node-gyp/9.8.0/include/node/v8config.h:318:3: note: in definition of macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
     declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
     ^
    SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
    COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
    COPY /home/ubuntu/dne/ne-backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node
    TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
  make: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/dne/ne-backend/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  npm WARN saas@1.0.0 No description
  npm WARN saas@1.0.0 No repository field.

  + bcrypt@1.0.3
  added 5 packages in 5.937s
```